# Git: A ton of blank lines showing up in diff when I haven't modified them

Tags: git, vim, version-control, github, configuration

Extremely frustrated. I have diffs that look like this (going on and on for nearly the whole file, in nearly every file I edit):[image: file diff]

even though I only modified one line. I have tried adjusting various `core` git config settings like `autocrlf`, `whitespace`, and `safecrlf`. I tried adding a `git/info/attributes` file that contains `* -crlf` to try to ignore any line ending differences, in case that's the cause.

I seem to be the only one in my office having this issue despite having identical config settings. I'm using Vim, but I can't see that it would be causing this issue, but I'm the only one using it so that's the consensus, and I can't explain it.

Is there a way to eliminate these kinds of whitespace differences?

Comment: What's in your Vim configuration?  Vim has [options](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format) for line endings and perhaps it's set wrongly for you.

Comment: @Idav1s Thanks for guiding me to the .vimrc options, in hindsight I should have probably looked there if not first, then at least second. I had a function `stripBadWhitespace` that was automatically removing trailing whitespace. Apparently our repo has a ton of these "errors" and all of those edits where happening automatically as I opened the file. You could leave an answer that states "How about you check your editor's config file regarding whitespace?" with or without "Dumbass" at the end. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, because I probably couldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a Vim guy, but I know a few things about it, like it's very customizable, and has options for line endings, etc.  Since these get introduced by just altering *one* line of code, it seems to me that Vim might be "fixing" the lines you didn't knowingly alter, and git is just displaying the result of that.

Comment: Yes, this was it. Thanks. I consider myself at least somewhat a Vim guy. I should have known better.

Answer (score 2):

You may be changing the [file format](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-14.13) when you edit the file, thus converting the line terminations, for example from CR to CR+LF or EOL.

You can check the file format before and after editing the file with `:set ff`.

---

The change on whitespace that you noticed with the aid of ldav1s can be seem on Vim with the `'list'` option:

```
:set list
```

Answer (score 2):

`git diff -w` ignores whitespace changes. You can also try `--word-diff`, which behaves differently but also ignores whitespace.

Comment: I know that removes the whitespace differences from the diff when I look at it, but when I commit the code, those whitespace differences are still in the commit when my colleagues look at it.